# What is meant by the perturbed Hamiltonian when calculating energy shifts?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, definition, hamiltonian, perturbation-theory

When calculating a shift in energy (or expectation value of the Hamiltonian) when doing perturbation theory in 1d, we do the following: $$\Delta E= \langle\hat{H}\rangle=\int\psi^*H_{\text{perturbed}}\psi ~\mathrm dx.$$ My question here is what exactly $H_{\text{perturbed}}$ is, and I have two options:

1. It is the shift in the Hamiltonian (i.e. $H_{\text{pert}}=H(x+dx)-H(x))$, or
2. It is the new Hamiltonian after the shift (i.e. $H_{\text{pert}}=H(x+dx)$.

Which of these options is the perturbed Hamiltonian?

Comment: Its case 2. The perturbed Hamiltonian is the total Hamiltonian after the perturbation is applied. Edit: rereading your question, while that is normally what is meant by "the perturbed Hamiltonian", $\Delta E$ normally refers to the energy shift, which would be calculated using the "perturbing Hamiltonian", that is case 1.

Comment: In which cases would you use the total Hamiltonian after the perturbation is applied?

Answer (score 1):

Perturbation theory is a method of approximating the eigenvalues of a Hamiltonian $H$ by studying a similar Hamiltonian $H_0$ whose eigenvalues $E_0$ and eigenfunctions are known. The two Hamiltonians are related by $$H=H_0+V $$  V is called the pertubation, $H_0$ is called the unperturbed Hamiltonian, while $H $ is known as the perturbed Hamiltonian.  For more details see:  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perturbation_theory_(quantum_mechanics)

Comment: OK so this is in contradiction with the comment on my question. From what you are saying I should be using $H_0+V$, but in this situation (i.e. where I am calculating the energy shift) the commenter is saying that I should be using $H-H_0$. Which is true?

Comment: I would have thought that the calculation should be $\int \psi^*(H_0+V)\psi$, which is what you are saying I believe.

Comment: Usually one approximates the eigenvalue of $H$ as $$E=E_0+<\psi_0|V|\psi_0>$$ where $E_0$ is the eigenvalue of $H_0$ and $V=H-H_0$ and $\psi_0$ is the eigenfunction of $H_0$.